# Why is std::invocable concept blocking this code from compiling

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, invocable

I do not understand why neither the lambda nor the function are recognized as an `std::invocable` compliant types in the following code:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

void f( std::invocable auto callback)
{
    callback(47);
}

void function_callback(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

auto lambda_callback = [](int i )
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
};

int main(int) 
{
    f(&function_callback);
    f(lambda_callback);
}
```

I am using GCC trunk with `-std=c++2a` flag enabled.

Comment: If you get build errors, always copy-paste them in full and complete and as text into the question itself. And add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [`invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) (or in the [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.invocable)):

```
template< class F, class... Args >
concept invocable =
  requires(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      /* not required to be equality preserving */
  };
```

What this means:

```
void f( std::invocable auto callback)
```

And it might be clearer if we write it long-form:

```
template <typename F>
    requires std::invocable<F>
void f(F callback);
```

Is that `F` is invocable with *no arguments* - that it's a nullary function (`Args...` is an empty pack here). Neither your function nor your lambda are nullary functions - they're both unary, so the constraint correctly rejects those.

What you probably want is:

```
void f( std::invocable<int> auto callback)
```

which checks if `callback` is invocable with a single argument of type `int`.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I have understood the reason why `Args...` is considered a *no argument* instead of being deduced to `int` automatically, but your proposed fix works.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 Concepts are _never_ deduced. Concepts are specified.

Comment: is there a way to really say "any" invocable type using concepts, without rolling back to template syntax?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 What would you even do with that information? You have a template that's constrained on a type that's invocable _somehow_ - but you don't know how? In the general sense, it's not possible to even answer.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: Remember: constraints are supposed to express how you intend to use a thing. You aren't going to call it with "any" arguments; you're going to call it with *some* arguments. So your constraint should express your intentions on your usage of the function.

Comment: What should we use if we want to validate the return type too. Is there a concept for that. I checked there is std:: is_invocable_r which is not a concept. Looking to check if there is aconcept